# How do I edit my MySQL request max case outputs?

Tags: mysql

When I run the following query.

```sql
SELECT tblhostingaddons.id as id, 
MAX(CASE WHEN (tblcustomfields.fieldname = 'boyut') THEN tblcustomfields.fieldoptions ELSE NULL END) AS quota,
MAX(CASE WHEN (tblcustomfields.fieldname = 'adet') THEN tblcustomfields.fieldoptions ELSE NULL END) AS pc,
MAX(CASE WHEN (tblcustomfields.fieldname = 'gonderimlimiti') THEN tblcustomfields.fieldoptions ELSE NULL END) AS send,
MAX(CASE WHEN (tblcustomfields.fieldname = 'turu') THEN tblcustomfields.fieldoptions ELSE NULL END) AS type 
FROM `tblhostingaddons` 
LEFT JOIN tbladdons ON tbladdons.id = tblhostingaddons.addonid 
LEFT JOIN tblcustomfields ON tblcustomfields.relid = tbladdons.id 
WHERE tblhostingaddons.hostingid = '88'
AND tblhostingaddons.status = 'Active' 
GROUP BY tblhostingaddons.id 
ORDER BY tblhostingaddons.id
```

The following result comes up. But I just want the **type** to come in lines that are **epostapro**.

```
id quota pc     send type
74 5120   1     200  epostapro
75 NULL   NULL  NULL NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using having clause:

```
SELECT tblhostingaddons.id as id, 
MAX(CASE WHEN (tblcustomfields.fieldname = 'boyut') THEN tblcustomfields.fieldoptions ELSE NULL END) AS boyut,
MAX(CASE WHEN (tblcustomfields.fieldname = 'adet') THEN tblcustomfields.fieldoptions ELSE NULL END) AS adet,
MAX(CASE WHEN (tblcustomfields.fieldname = 'gonderimlimiti') THEN tblcustomfields.fieldoptions ELSE NULL END) AS gonderimlimiti,
MAX(CASE WHEN (tblcustomfields.fieldname = 'turu') THEN tblcustomfields.fieldoptions ELSE NULL END) AS turu 
FROM `tblhostingaddons` 
LEFT JOIN tbladdons ON tbladdons.id = tblhostingaddons.addonid 
LEFT JOIN tblcustomfields ON tblcustomfields.relid = tbladdons.id 
WHERE tblhostingaddons.hostingid = '88'
AND tblhostingaddons.status = 'Active' 
GROUP BY tblhostingaddons.id 
having MAX(CASE WHEN (tblcustomfields.fieldname = 'turu') THEN tblcustomfields.fieldoptions ELSE NULL END)='epostapro'
ORDER BY tblhostingaddons.id
```

OR you can remove id from selection list as well as group by 
like below:

```
SELECT  
MAX(CASE WHEN (tblcustomfields.fieldname = 'boyut') THEN tblcustomfields.fieldoptions ELSE NULL END) AS boyut,
MAX(CASE WHEN (tblcustomfields.fieldname = 'adet') THEN tblcustomfields.fieldoptions ELSE NULL END) AS adet,
MAX(CASE WHEN (tblcustomfields.fieldname = 'gonderimlimiti') THEN tblcustomfields.fieldoptions ELSE NULL END) AS gonderimlimiti,
MAX(CASE WHEN (tblcustomfields.fieldname = 'turu') THEN tblcustomfields.fieldoptions ELSE NULL END) AS turu 
FROM `tblhostingaddons` 
LEFT JOIN tbladdons ON tbladdons.id = tblhostingaddons.addonid 
LEFT JOIN tblcustomfields ON tblcustomfields.relid = tbladdons.id 
WHERE tblhostingaddons.hostingid = '88'
AND tblhostingaddons.status = 'Active'
```